# Jenkins Bitbucket hook hanging on git ls-remote command

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I have an instance of Jenkins running and the BitBucket plugin installed, with the checkbox ticked to build when a commit is pushed to BitBucket.

I believe that the BitBucket webhook is set up correctly because I can see the requests returning a 200 response in the logs for the webhook. The URL that I'm using for the webhook to Jenkins is formatted as:

https://username:apiKey@JENKINS_URL/bitbucket-hook/?Jenkins-Crumb=GENERATED_CSRF_CRUMB

In Jenkins, I can see that in the 'bitbucket hook log', Jenkins tries to issue git commands, but times out. Here is the last log from the plugin:

```
Started on Oct 12, 2016 2:08:19 PM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 1e47f849c9a899582dee0199abb208c0a3ca40ee (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials The SSH Key for Jenkins to pull from bitbucket
 > git.exe ls-remote -h https://bitbucket.org//USER/PROJECT.git # timeout=10
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Failed to join a process
org.jvnet.winp.WinpException: Failed to read environment variable table error=299 at .\envvar-cmdline.cpp:201
    at org.jvnet.winp.Native.getCmdLineAndEnvVars(Native Method)
    at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.parseCmdLineAndEnvVars(WinProcess.java:126)
    at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.getCommandLine(WinProcess.java:102)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Windows$1.getArguments(ProcessTree.java:441)
    at hudson.plugins.msbuild.MsBuildKillingVeto.vetoProcessKilling(MsBuildKillingVeto.java:55)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$OSProcess.getVeto(ProcessTree.java:239)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Windows$1.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:422)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree.killAll(ProcessTree.java:142)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.destroy(Proc.java:378)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.kill(Proc.java:370)
    at hudson.Proc$1.run(Proc.java:157)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I believe that the SSH keys are setup correctly because they work for manual builds and other jobs.

I know that the error returned after the timeout is related to an authentication/permissions error, but Jenkins is able to run other git commands during manual builds.

This is the same issue described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840486/bitbucket-build-erring-after-triggered-from-commit) question, but I have tried using both SSH keys and username/password as credentials and I still get the same issue.

Has anyone experienced this error, or have I badly configured something on the Jenkins server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looking at this bit `using GIT_SSH to set credentials The SSH Key for Jenkins to pull from bitbucket
 > git.exe ls-remote -h https://bitbucket.org//aber-project.git`  , is the repository URL correct? If you are using SSH for authentication shouldn't the URL be something like `git@bitbucket.org:YOURUSER/aber-project.git` ?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I changed the url for the purpose of the question and missed out the user. I'll update that now to something more generic